# Dynamic Quad/Oct Trees

Tags: data-structure, octree, quadtree, c++

I've recently discovered the power of Quadtrees and Octrees and their role in culling/LOD applications, however I've been pondering on the implementations for a Dynamic Quad/Oct Tree.

Such tree would not require a complete rebuild when some of the underlying data changes (Vertex Data).

Would it be possible to create such a tree? What would that look like? Could someone point me in the correct direction to get started?

The application here would, in my scenario, be used for a dynamically changing spherical landscape with over 10,000,000 verticies. The use of Quad/Oct Trees is obvious for Culling & LOD as well as the benefits from not having to completely recompute the tree when the underlying data changes.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by dynamic in this situation? Nodes are added and removed dynamically? The data within the nodes is dynamic?

Comment: The vertex data within the nodes can and will change. So instead of having to recompute the entire tree each time an arbitrarily small amount of data changes, can the tree 'update' adding/removing nodes depending on what data has changed?

Comment: I believe he's using voxels as points in space. These voxels often change, so he is wondering how to avoid the need to rebuild the tree every time a voxel changes. E.g, one voxel changes from green to red. That would require that sphere's region of the tree to be recalculated because the region was made to have only green spheres.

Comment: Essentially you are correct. The tree representing the 10M verts would need reconstructed if only 1 vert changes which would be a waste of performance.

Comment: The entire quadtree/octree doesn't need to be reconstructed when an object is added/removed/changed.  Just like in any other tree data structure, you only have to fix up the tree after the modification so that it complies with the constraints of your implementation.

Comment: Okay! That's great news! I was almost sure I didn't have to reconstruct the entire thing. Now, would you have any links/example that could help me learn how to accomplish this? Thank you very much.

Comment: There's basically only two operations you need: when a cluster of 4/8 leaf nodes drops below a threshold density, merge them into their shared parent. When a leaf node exceeds a threshold density, split it into 4/8 child leaves. All the other details depend on how you're storing your tree.

Comment: Please take further discussion to chat.

Comment: Another variation you could consider is "loose octrees". They handle dynamic data very well (insertion in constant time).

Comment: Yes I've seen articles on loose octrees however a majority of the time the mesh does not change so I think a lot of performance would be lost using loose trees in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few 2d implementations of dynamic spatial structures located here:

https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/Steerio/tree/master/Java/src/org/magnos/steer/spatial

As far as quad/octrees go, each iteration you check on everything in the database to see whether it has changed which node it belongs to. In my tree implementations I keep an entity in the highest node in which it is fully contained. That involves some simple logic:

```
am I fully contained in the current node?
   try to push up parent node
else if this node has children?
   can any of the current node's children contain me?
      push down to child
```

I'll make it more efficient by having flags for whether an entity has moved... the ones that don't can be skipped.